# Unable to install and run VMware 12.0.0 in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, vmware-workstation

I have recently installed Ubuntu 17.04 and wanted to install VMware workstation.
Then when I tried to run the program the vmware kernel module updater failed to install modules.

I tried to apply solution from this link: 
[Vmware Workstation on Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905200/vmware-workstation-on-ubuntu-17-04)

and I cannot find what mentioned in that thread in the hostif.c and userif.c files.

I hope if someone can help me out here.

If anyone wants to look into those files please tell me how I can provide you them. I'm new here.

Thanks,

Comment: You could use `kvm` for virtualization!  Otherwise, you might try a more recent version of the workstation, like version 12.5.6

Comment: actually I need to use VMware workstation because I have to practice VCP-DC6. So, I'll try using latest version.

Comment: hey charles, I did what you said and it worked totally fine. It was easy one but thanks for your help though.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked!